# Bootstrap button for Table Print

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a bootstrap table in my html page.
Following the bootstrap documentation https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/print/ , i downloaded and inserted extensions folder in my project.
I created a print button

```
<div id="toolbar"> 
   <button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-lg'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-print' aria-hidden='true'></span> Stampa mancanti</button> 
</div> 
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" data-toolbar="#toolbar">
```

inserted in my page

`<script src="extensions/print/bootstrap-table-print.js"></script>`

but when i press the PRINT button nothing happen.
All other glyphicon buttons (edit, add, delete, etc) works fine but they work with

`if(isset($_POST['edit'])){ ..... }`

I would like to do something like this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').DataTable({
                    responsive: true,
                    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',      
                    buttons: [
                        {
            extend:'print',
             exportOptions:{columns:[0,1,2]} 
            },          
            'excelHtml5',            
            'pdfHtml5'
                    ],
                    "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Italian.json"
                }
                });
            });

    </script>
```

but using Bootstrap glyphicon buttons

Answer (score 4):

Try this

Right Way:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.15.4/extensions/print/bootstrap-table-print.js"></script>
```

Wrong Way:

```
<script src="extensions/print/bootstrap-table-print.js"></script>
```

Comment: The wrong way it's written on bootstrap documentation https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/print/ Also the right way don't work.

Comment: The documentation say: showPrint. Detail: Set true to show the Print button on the toolbar. Default: false. How to change from false to true?

Comment: Which is the correct form to make the print button appear on the table? ```<table id="example" data-pagination="true" data-show-print="true" data-show-toggle="true">```

Comment: If i see https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#extensions/print.html and then go on the source code https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#extensions/print.html#view-source when i launch the page (copy/paste & save as .php) on a browser don't see the table and the button